# How to do a case sensitive GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

If I execute the code below:

```
with temp as
(
  select 'Test' as name
  UNION ALL
  select 'TEST'
  UNION ALL
  select 'test'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
)
SELECT name, COUNT(name)
FROM temp
group by name
```

It returns the results:

```
TEST   3
tester 2
```

Is there a way to have the group by be case sensitive so that the results would be:

```
Test   1
TEST   1
test   1
tester 2
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use an case sensitive collation:

```
with temp as
(
  select 'Test' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS as name
  UNION ALL
  select 'TEST'
  UNION ALL
  select 'test'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
)
SELECT name, COUNT(name)
FROM temp
group by name
```

Answer (score 39):

You need to cast the text as binary (or use a case-sensitive collation).

```
With temp as
(
  select 'Test' as name
  UNION ALL
  select 'TEST'
  UNION ALL
  select 'test'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
)
Select Name, COUNT(name)
From temp
Group By Name, Cast(name As varbinary(100))
```

Using a collation:

```
Select Name Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, COUNT(name)
From temp
Group By Name Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: Are there reasons to choose one method over the other?

Comment: The second one can use if you don't know what possible values a table could have.

Comment: For MySQL, just replace `VARBINARY` with `BINARY`, and it works fine.

Answer (score 23):

Simply:

```
SELECT count(*), CAST(lastname as BINARY) AS lastname_cs 
FROM names 
GROUP BY lastname_cs;
```

Comment: In SQL server, this returns the last name in binary like 0x43002D003100200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000. There might be some way to convert it back to a String, but for SQL Server it might be better to just use the collation as suggested in a different answer. e.g. select 'Test' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS as name

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL/MariaDB, if you don't want to use collations or casting to binary, just use:

```
SELECT MAX(name), COUNT(name)
FROM (
  select 'Test' as name
  UNION ALL
  select 'TEST'
  UNION ALL
  select 'test'
  UNION ALL
  select 'test'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
  UNION ALL
  select 'tester'
) as tmp
group by MD5(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on my case:

`SELECT BINARY example FROM table GROUP BY BINARY example;`

Comment: This works in MySQL, but does not work in SQL Server. IDK about other databases

Comment: In JDBC, I found this returned binary data instead of String data. So, I ended up using the collation approach instead: 

SELECT example collate utf8mb4_bin FROM table GROUP BY example collate utf8mb4_bin