# How to "group by" in strict string comparation when sql_mode=only_full_group_by is setted in MySql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to group by `t0.method` in strict string comparation, i.e. "GET ", "GET" and "get" in different group, so a `BINARY` is added in front of the `t0.method` field which appears in the group by sentence. but **I can't add a `BINARY` to this field which appears in the select sentence, since this will cause an encoding problem when non-ascii characters appears in the data**.

So following is the SQL query I finally get:

```
SELECT `t0`.`method` AS `d0`,
  SUM(`t0`.`success`) AS `m0`
FROM `invoke_statistics` AS `t0`
GROUP BY BINARY `t0`.`method`
LIMIT 20000
```

But unfortunately, I got the following error message then..

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 't0.method' which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

So, what is the correct way to do all this without causing any encoding problem or incompatibility problem with the "sql_mode=only_full_group_by" things?

**NOTE:**

1. I'm not able to modify the sql_mode option.
2. I'm not able to make sure that there is no non-ascii characters appears in the data
3. I'm not able to know what char set is used before generate a query. so the `collate utf8_bin` or similar things is not able to work since it may cause some errors like `COLLATION 'UTF8_BIN' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

**I'm doing something about code generation, so the other's answer which depends on a lot of assumptions can't solve my problem, I need some general solution**

Comment: Try `SELECT t0.method COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS...`

Comment: Or Google `SQL GROUP BY CASE SENSITIVE`

Comment: @sagi   I'v found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952696/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-group-by) but there is nothing helpful ..

Comment: @sagi I spent 7 or 8 minutes on this with collation utf8mb4 or something before I closed it. If one of you guys (I will ask Rick) can take a look. It is reopened now

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following work when the SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY:

Make your grouping column part of the select-list:

```
SELECT BINARY `t0`.`method` AS `d0`,
  SUM(`t0`.`success`) AS `m0`
FROM `invoke_statistics` AS `t0`
GROUP BY BINARY `t0`.`method`
LIMIT 20000
```

Or make your select-list use an aggregate function:

```
SELECT MAX(`t0`.`method`) AS `d0`,
  SUM(`t0`.`success`) AS `m0`
FROM `invoke_statistics` AS `t0`
GROUP BY BINARY `t0`.`method`
LIMIT 20000
```

I tested both of these queries on MySQL 8.0 DMR.

Answer (score 0):

(There seem to be two questions rolled into one.  This addresses the collation problem.)

**Plan A**

The "right" answer is to change the collation in the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
    method ... COLLATE xxx_bin
    ...
```

Where xxx is the charset involved.  That is (apparently), `latin1_bin`.  ("Latin1_General_CS_AS" comes from some other vendor, not MySQL.)

Caveat:  This will affect all other comparisons (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `=`) involving the column `method`.  (This may or may not be an issue.)

**Plan B**

The way to do it in the query is

```
... GROUP BY method COLLATE latin1_bin ...
```

A `COLLATE` clause can be tacked onto a variety of things, including comparisons and `ORDER BY`.  But, note, it prevents the use of an index for optimization.

Comment: thx for your reply, but, 1. I can't change the definition of the table, 2. I'm not sure what the char set is used in the original table, so the ` COLLATE latin1_bin ` solution may cause an error in mysql...