# Will a binary operator used in group by prevent the use of an index for optimization?

Tags: mysql, performance

i.e.  there is an index for `invoke_statistics.method`

```
SELECT MAX(`t0`.`method`) AS `d0`,
  SUM(`t0`.`success`) AS `m0`
FROM `invoke_statistics` AS `t0`
GROUP BY BINARY `t0`.`method`
LIMIT 20000
```

Will the `BINARY` operator used in the `GROUP BY` sentence prevent the use of the index for optimization?

If yes, then, what is the recommended way to `group by` a string field via strict string comparation instead of using `BINARY`, considering I have no permission to change the table definition?

Comment: In my experience, almost anything in a query prevents MySQL from using indexes for `GROUP BY` optimization.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I don't understand this query.  Why not write:

```
SELECT BINARY t0.method d0, SUM(t0.success) AS m0
FROM invoke_statistics as t0
GROUP BY BINARY t0.method;
```

The initial `MAX()` shouldn't be doing anything (how can two values in a column be *the same* in the binary representation but different in their actually representation?).

Then, to answer your question, MySQL does take collation into account when creating indexes -- it has to, because collations define ordering.  Because `BINARY` changes the collation, I would expect it to preclude index usage.  This is not a 100% certainty; it is an expectation.

Comment: the reason why I write this query is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396426/how-to-group-by-in-strict-string-comparation-when-sql-mode-only-full-group-by), in short, select binary is not friendly with non-ascii string.