# Count occurence of attribute values in each row with case-sensitive in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive

I have table (**notes_subject**) structure -

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| note_id      | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subject_name | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and data stored in this table -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
| 10 |       2 | UdMs870BSswp | CN           |
| 12 |       2 | 8stMvslwIGr2 | CN           |
| 13 |       2 | PB3KNbbFkaUm | cn           |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Note : CN and cn (lowercase) are different.

I want to count the occurence of each `subject_name` by `user_id` in this table. So I run query -

```
SELECT subject_name, COUNT(subject_name) 
FROM notes_subject where user_id=2 GROUP BY subject_name;
```

and it fetched -

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| subject_name | COUNT(subject_name) |
+--------------+---------------------+
| CN           |                   3 |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

But this is not correct result because CN and cn are different.
and I also want id, user_id, note_id in the result.

Comment: This is probably related to the collation. I would suggest to search for something like [How to do a case sensitive GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952696/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-group-by). But that question is specific for SQL Server, so it might be different depending on your DB.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I have tried this query - `SELECT  subject_name, COUNT(subject_name) FROM notes_subject GROUP BY subject_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` but it is giving error

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql answer your question

Comment: @HernánAlarcón `Unknown collation` error occured, I see the accepted answer in the link which you shared. He is giving **all values manually** of each rows.

Comment: @carljohnson What is your DB? SQL is a language

Comment: I am using MySql version 8.0.21 in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database support `window functions`, I think you want something like this. Try with `collate utf8mb4_bin` to see if that helps with case sensitivity you need

```
select id, 
       user_id, 
       note_id, 
       subject_name, 
       count(subject_name collate utf8mb4_bin) over (partition by user_id, subject_name collate utf8mb4_bin) 
from notes_subject;
```

If `window functions` are out of question, you can also aggregate separately and join it back to the main table.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=deb9ea587ff51156cc76fbd3577e9882)

Comment: Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS' error occured. I am using MySql `8.0.21` in ubuntu.

Comment: @carljohnson It's because the solution was for SQL Server. Try now

Comment: @carljohnson That I am not sure as I have never worked with one before

Answer (score 0):

Posting another alternative which is by `selecting the group by column as a binary field`.

Tested in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2f74cacd2440e963c68259a36025201) with MYSQL 8.0 version

```
SELECT cast(subject_name as binary) subject_name, COUNT(subject_name)  cnt
  FROM notes_subject 
 WHERE user_id=2 
GROUP BY cast(subject_name as binary)
```

Comment: But what if I have tons of rows in DB, then I have to write `SELECT 10, 12, 13 ,14... `.

Comment: No No I just used CTE for demo purpose. just use like SELECT cast(subject_name as binary) subject_name, COUNT(subject_name)  cnt
  FROM notes_subject 
 WHERE user_id=2 
GROUP BY cast(subject_name as binary)

Comment: check the dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2f74cacd2440e963c68259a36025201

Comment: It is giving the value of subject_name  as **0x434E** instead of CN and **0x636E** instead of  cn.

Comment: I have provided the fiddle link with MYSQL 8.0 and its working. Not sure why it changes the value and may be because of any parameter setting on DB level. For the moment please ignore and go with the window clause solution. I will check and update if i found anything

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Binary to cast it.

```
SELECT count(*), CAST(subject_name as BINARY) AS lastname_cs 
FROM notes_subject where user_id=2 
GROUP BY CAST(subject_name as BINARY);
```

Comment: what is lastname_cs, I think it's a CPY post

Comment: thats the table I created on my local machine.